# Laravel cannot do any migration. SQL 42000 error. Migration refresh, reset, rollback nothing works

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-artisan, migrate

This is the error when trying to do a migration: 
 SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that    corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'by `batch` asc, `migration` asc' at lin   e 1

Agents Migration:

```
Schema::create('agents', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('first_name');
    $table->string('last_name');
    $table->string('phone');

    $table->string('email')->unique();

   $table->string('password');

    $table->string('agency_name')->nullable();

    $table->string('address');

    $table->string('city');

    $table->string('zip_code');


    $table->string('status');

    $table->timestamps();
```

Users Migration

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('first_name');
    $table->string('last_name');
    $table->string('phone');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->string('password');
    $table->string('agency_name')->nullable();
    $table->string('address');
    $table->string('city');
    $table->string('zipcode');
    $table->string('user_type');
    $table->string('status');
    $table->string('otp');
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

It's not the migration issue. I removed all migration and tried migration reset and refresh still the error. I removed all the tables and tried to migrate with only one table which is the Laravel users migration. Still the error.

Comment: show your model code @Sanjay R Nath

Comment: show your migration code please

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have edited the answer with migration. Model is a generic model created by laravel. Has not edited it.